# How to display data in a map so that redundancy is not there in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

say i have state of my component as

```
 todo:
{
value:1
}
```

Now i have a component that prints data as

```
<div>
{this.state.todo.map(function(todo,i)
{
<h1>{todo.value}</h1>
)}

</div>
```

i have an input text field add button in my form also and when if i write **2** and then click add then value should be added in the state as now it will look like

```
 todo:{
value:1
},
{
value:2
}
```

Now i want to show my result like

```
<div>
1
</div>

<div>
2
</div>
```

But what i am getting is(for obvious reasons)

```
   <div>
    1
    2
    </div>

    <div>
 1   
 2
    </div>
```

Error what i am getting is if i send my state to child component as

```
<Child item={this.state.todo[1].value}/>
```

then if i add 2 in my form then only 2 will get printed because index0 is not being selected.

I am not able to catch the approach which will help e to achieve this.

Stuck from hours.

Please help!

[image: screenshot]
here subtasks of second main task are reflected in first main task and vice versa

Comment: Firstly what if you do this,
`<div>
{this.state.todo.map(function(todo,i)
{
<div>{todo.value}</div>
)}
</div>` , I think it will be in separate divs.

Also if you're passing it to the child, send `i` as array index i.e. 
`<Child item={this.state.todo[i].value}/>`

Comment: for first click it will print 1 in first div and if elements kees on adding then it will keep adding previous elements in all the divisions but i want that if loop is running for 7th index then only 7th element should be printed in 7th div,while all the previous elements should be printed in their respective divs and not mess with each other

Comment: Is this all your code? Isn't there another `map` surrounding `this.state.todo.map(...)`?

Comment: my code is very large.so i just asked the problem that i am facing and how wrapping it with another map would  solve my problem?

Comment: Help me understand this, you don't want it to re render the previous divs OR there are 7 divs each having text 1-7 ?

Comment: yes there are 7 divs each having text as div1 having only 1 div2 having only 2.......div7 having only 7:)

Comment: But if the state is getting changed, react will re render the parent component and you don't want it to re render everything , right ?

Comment: yes right you got it now

Comment: It's not a flaw, React is built this way and it'll re-render if there is a change in state. If I may, how does it affect you, because you wouldn't be able to notice the difference I suppose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149751/discussion-between-vipul-singh-and-vikram-saini).